# HandlebarsJs inside a jquery request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars to display a set of javascript arrays in an html.

The javascript arrays look like this

```
[{pid:"1mn0wZj6yN", id:"yUjCaVzZ3CcCdOj"},{pid:"uEG9LXUaZi", id:"0eamlmJAFd2Ltwd"}]
```

Make a jquery get request to get this array

```
$.get( "file.php", function( respo ) {
       var temmple = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());
       $('#container').append(temmple(respo));      
  });
```

This is the handle bars template

```
 <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          {{#each this}}
          <p>{{id}}</p>
          {{/each}}
 </script>
```

It appears that the problem is that the handlebars compile and appending doesn't work within the jquery get request, why is that? what's the way to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the result of console.log(JSON.stringify(respo)) ?

Comment: @akhikhl "[{\"pid\":\"1mn0wZj6yN\",\"id\":\"yUjCaVzZ3CcCdOj\"...............

Comment: What is the `typeof respo`? If `file.php` is outputting the JavaScript in your 1st snippet, jQuery won't automatically eval it from a `String` of code to the `Array` it's trying to describe. You should consider outputting JSON instead with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode), which jQuery will try to parse.

Comment: It looks like your JSON object is being interpreted as a string, and isn't formed into JSON.

Comment: @dc2 yah thanks a lot, adding a jQuery.parseJSON did the trick :) if you can add that as a detailed answer i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON, it is just coming back as a blob of text from your server:

```
$.get( "file.php", function(respo) {
  respo = $.parseJSON(respo);
  var temmple = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());
  $('#container').append(temmple(respo));      
});
```